# How to get every other element in xml(iconCode)

Tags: c#, xml

First `dailyForecastPeriods` is for the day forecast and the second is for the night forecast and so on. I would like to loop and get the odd number `iconCode`, 1,3,5,7 and so on. Below in `C#` I have a foreach loop that grabs each instance of the iconCode, but as a result it only shows the last iconCode in the xml. I need help applying each iconCode as a string, format it like below, and adding it to the xml to be applied to the xsl sheet. You can see what I added in the xml at the end of the code.

`C#:`

```
         XDocument scan = XDocument.Parse(xNode.ToString());
         foreach (XElement element in scan.Descendants("iconCode"))
                {
                  iconCode1 = element.Value;
                }

         Int32 result;                             
         Int32.TryParse(iconCode1, out result);
         string iconFilename2 = "cond" + string.Format("{0:00#}", result) + ".png";

         xFore.Root.Add(new XElement("img_small", weatherImages + @"Small/" + iconFilename2),
         new XElement("img_large", weatherImages + @"Large/" + iconFilename2));
```

`XML:`

```
<forecast>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>3</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>81.1</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Highs in the lower 80s. East winds 5 to 10 mph.      </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>2</iconCode>
     <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
     <temperature>63</temperature>
     <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Lows in the lower 60s. East winds 5 to 10 mph.   </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>3</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>82</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Highs in the lower 80s. East winds 10 to 15 mph. </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>2</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>65</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Lows in the mid 60s. Northeast winds 10 to 15 mph. </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>3</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>82</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Highs in the lower 80s. Northeast winds 5 to 10 mph. </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>73</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>Mostly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>67</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Mostly cloudy. Lows in the mid 60s. </detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>93</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>30% Chance of Storms</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>82</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Partly sunny with a chance of showers and thunderstorms. Highs in the lower 80s. Chance of rain 30 percent</detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>105</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>30% Chance of Storms</summaryDescription>
      <temperature>64</temperature>
      <detailedDescription>Mostly cloudy with a chance of showers and thunderstorms. Lows in the mid 60s. Chance of rain 30 percent. </detailedDescription>
   </dailyForecastPeriods>
   <dailyForecastPeriods>
      <iconCode>95</iconCode>
      <summaryDescription>50% Chance of Storms</summaryDescription
<temperature>81.1</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly sunny with a chance of showers and thunderstorms. Highs in the lower 80s. Chance of rain 50 percent</detailedDescription>
    </dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>2</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>61.1</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Lows in the lower 60s. </detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>3</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>78</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Highs in the upper 70s. </detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>2</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>58</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Lows in the upper 50s. </detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>3</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>78</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. Highs in the upper 70s. </detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>70</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Mostly Clear</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>56.3</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Mostly clear. Low temperature around 56F. Dew point will be around 50F with an average humidity of 61%. Winds will be 7 mph from the WNW.</detailedDescription>
    </dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>26</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Mostly Sunny</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>74.5</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Mostly sunny. High temperature around 74F. Dew point will be around 50F with an average humidity of 53%. Winds will be 9 mph from the WNW.</detailedDescription>
    </dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>31</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Clear</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>60.4</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Clear. Low temperature around 60F. Dew point will be around 52F with an average humidity of 63%. Winds will be 4 mph from the NNW.</detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>7</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Sunny</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>76.3</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Sunny. High temperature around 76F. Dew point will be around 54F with an average humidity of 57%. Winds will be 4 mph from the NW.</detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>31</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Clear</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>62.1</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Clear. Low temperature around 62F. Dew point will be around 55F with an average humidity of 65%. Winds will be 2 mph from the WSW.</detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>3</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Partly Cloudy</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>76.6</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Partly cloudy. High temperature around 77F. Dew point will be around 55F with an average humidity of 59%. Winds will be 4 mph from the W.</detailedDescription></dailyForecastPeriods>
    <dailyForecastPeriods>
    <iconCode>70</iconCode>
    <summaryDescription>Mostly Clear</summaryDescription>
    <temperature>62.2</temperature>
    <detailedDescription>Mostly clear. Low temperature around 62F. Dew point will be around 55F with an average humidity of 65%. Winds will be 4 mph from the WSW.</detailedDescription>
    </dailyForecastPeriods>
    <img_small>https://hylantnet.hylant.com/WeatherImages/Small/cond070.png</img_small>
```

https://hylantnet.hylant.com/WeatherImages/Large/cond070.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal that only the last element is treated as you navigate through all your elements and store them in the same variable. As a result, each value overrides the previous one.

If you want to avoid this behavior, you can execute your treatments inside the foreach loop just like this:

```
foreach (XElement element in scan.Descendants("iconCode"))
{
     string iconCode1 = element.Value;
     Int32 result;                             
     Int32.TryParse(iconCode1, out result);
     string iconFilename2 = "cond" + string.Format("{0:00#}", result) + ".png";

     xFore.Root.Add(new XElement("img_small", weatherImages + @"Small/" + iconFilename2),
     new XElement("img_large", weatherImages + @"Large/" + iconFilename2));
}
```